# How to run Azure Storage Emulator on remote machine when no user is logged in

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure-storage-emulator

I have a web application on one of the client's machines (a virtual machine running Windows Server 2012R2). The application uses Azure Storage. For testing purposes it was decided to use an Azure Storage Emulator.

My problem is that, when I log out of the remote machine the storage emulator stops. How do I keep the Azure Storage Emulator running even if no user is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

CristisS@, There are two possible solutions i could think off based on your scenario, the first one is to configure the emulator to be part of the startup programs, meaning, if the VM restarts, the application will automatically launch,all you have to do is add the emulator icon to the startup directory:
**1-** Enable viewing hidden files and folders
**2**  Navigate to: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`
Paste the Emulator icon there.

Another solution is by configuring autologon and linking the application to a specific user to allow the emulator to connect automatically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon

```
Autologon enables you to easily configure Windows’ built-in autologon mechanism. Instead of waiting for a user to enter their name and password, Windows uses the credentials you enter with Autologon, which are encrypted in the Registry, to log on the specified user automatically.
Autologon is easy enough to use. Just run autologon.exe, fill in the dialog, and hit Enable. To turn off auto-logon, hit Disable. Also, if the shift key is held down before the system performs an autologon, the autologon will be disabled for that logon. You can also pass the username, domain and password as command-line arguments:
autologon user domain password
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have moved on from that project and at the moment. Regarding your first solution, I have tried something similar to that approach, and it didn't work.
I think your second approach is the best way to go, but I cannot test that for the moment. I will upvote your answer, but not select it as the good one, because I am unable to test. Thank you for the suggestions!